# captcha dynamic renew with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

Would appreciate any piece of advice on this.
Need to dynamically renew the captcha image generated by php-script, 
when the "captcha_refresh" is clicked.
Below is the way I tried to achieve it. Unfortunately this approach works fine only with Google Chrome,
and other browsers seem not to understand this.

## HTML

```
<img class="captcha_image" src="http://localhost/shop/create_image.php"/>
<a class="captcha_refresh" href="http://localhost/shop/create_image.php">
    <img src="http://localhost/shop/images/captcha_refresh.png"/>
</a>
```

## JQuery

```
$('a.captcha_refresh').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('img.captcha_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

The PHP prints the image:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
ImageJpeg($captchaImage);
```

The approach like: `$('#someButton').click(function() { $('#someDiv').load('captcha.php'); });`
suggested at [PHP: Reloading the captcha image from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871966/php-reloading-the-captcha-image-from-javascript)
is not working.
Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a random query string to the image source:

```
$('img.captcha_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('href') + '?rand=' + Math.random());
```

You should also send `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers with the image and instruct the browser that it should not cache the image:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   // Date in the past
// rest of your image generation code
```

Comment: thanx, it absolutely worked. Sorry I haven't got enough reputation to vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try using more generic syntax :

```
$('.captcha_refresh').click(function () {
   $('.captcha_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
   return false;
});
```